# Apache/wsgi "Script timed out before returning headers"

Tags: django, wsgi

I have a custom Django app that's becoming unresponsive roughly every 5,000 requests. In the apache logs, I see see the following:

```
Apr 13 11:45:07 www3 apache2[27590]: **successful view render here**
...
Apr 13 11:47:11 www3 apache2[24032]: [error] server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxClients, consider raising the MaxClients setting
Apr 13 11:47:43 www3 apache2[24032]: [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
...
Apr 13 11:50:34 www3 apache2[27617]: [error] [client 10.177.0.204] Script timed out before returning headers: django.wsgi
(repeated 100 times, exactly)
```

I believe I am running WSGI 2.6 (/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.6) with the following config:

**apache config**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess site-1 user=django group=django threads=50
WSGIProcessGroup site-1
WSGIScriptAlias / /somepath/django.wsgi
```

**/somepath/django.wsgi**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/django')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'    
import django.core.handlers.wsgi    
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

When this happens, I can kill the wsgi process and the server will recover.

```
>ps aux|grep django # process is running as user "django"
django   27590  5.3 17.4 908024 178760 ?       Sl   Apr12  76:09 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>kill -9 27590
```

This leads me to believe that the problem is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess):

> **deadlock-timeout=sss (2.0+)**
>
> Defines the maximum number of seconds
>   allowed to pass before the daemon
>   process is shutdown and restarted
>   after a potential deadlock on the
>   Python GIL has been detected. The
>   default is 300 seconds. This option
>   exists to combat the problem of a
>   daemon process freezing as the result
>   of a rouge Python C extension module
>   which doesn't properly release the
>   Python GIL when entering into a
>   blocking or long running operation.

However, I'm not sure why this condition is not clearing automatically. I do see that the script timeout occurs exactly 5 minutes after the last successful page render, so the deadlock-timeout is getting triggered. But it does not actually kill the process.

**Edit: more info**

- apache version 2.2, using the **worker MPM**
- wsgi version 2.8
- SELinux NOT installed l
- xml package being used, infrequently
- Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: FYI - Some more info here http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/2b335de711908eb3

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a limit of requests after which the daemon processes are recycled (before an external process does it).
This is done by adding the `maximum-requests` parameter of `WSGIDaemonProcess`.

See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Defining_Process_Groups

Alternatively, you could investigate how much processes your 'django' user is allowed to have.
You can check this by opening a shell as that user `su - django -s /bin/bash` and checking output of `ulimit -a`.

Comment: My understanding is that `maximum-requests` should be avoided in production code. See this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/modwsgi/KzNd5xGQjrM/i5Dz7TBePNQJ

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using mod-wsgi in production anyway. There are nicer options in uWSGI, such as "cheaper": http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cheaper.html